# Retrieve Value from Object Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I'll go straight to the problem.

I have this array named

```
$datosUsuario['empleadoUsuario'] = $this->EmpleadoModel->get_empleado_vistaUsuario($result[0]->idusuario);
```

To show the values from **datosUsuario**

```
var_dump($datosUsuario['empleadoUsuario']);
```

The result speak by himself

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#26 (13) { ["nombreempresa"]=> string(7) "SERDIRH" ["email"]=> string(23) "luis.gomez@claro.com.ni" ["rutafoto"]=> string(24) "uploads/default-user.png" ["nombrecompleto"]=> string(24) "LUIS FELIPE GOMEZ ROBLES" ["carnetempleado"]=> string(6) "400387" ["direccion"]=> string(13) "SIN DIRECCION" ["telefono"]=> string(8) "88330377" ["dominioempleado"]=> string(10) "luis.gomez" ["fecha_ingreso"]=> string(10) "11/06/2012" ["nombreregion"]=> string(19) "CENTRO Y ESPECIALES" ["nombredepartamento"]=> string(4) "RAAS" ["nombretienda"]=> string(10) "BLUEFIELDS" ["idtienda"]=> int(81) } }
```

and when i try to obtain the value **idtienda** just gave me a NULL.

```
$data['idtienda'] = $empleadoUsuario[0]->idtienda;
```

Please tell me what im doing wrong.
The framework it's codeigniter.

Comment: did you try `$empleadoUsuario->idtienda;`

Comment: try this $datosUsuario['empleadoUsuario'][0]->idtienda;

Comment: @elddenmedio the result that gave it's Message: Undefined variable: empleadoUsuario

Comment: Try `$empleadoUsuario[0]['idtienda;']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
$data['idtienda'] = $empleadoUsuario[0]->idtienda;
```

with

```
$data['idtienda'] = $datosUsuario['empleadoUsuario'][0]->idtienda;
```